# Chrome JavaScript turned off

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Okay, here's my problem. I wrote some JavaScript for a page, for some reason the page doesn't work in Chrome. The site does what I expect in Opera, Chromium and Firefox. In the Choom devtools there is a kind of error showing in the source tab showing "JavScript is disabled" in a mouse hover popup:

[image]

I turned off all chrome's extensions, Javascript in on in the content settings and I cleared all JavaScript exceptions I had, but this didn't seem to change anything. The weird thing (an other one) is that some other sites give the same alert icon in the devtools (including this one) but JavaScript works just fine.

If you perform the exact same functions in the console then, some of, the functions perform just fine.

Does anyone have an idea what I could be because I am out of idea's and it is really annoying that I have to switch browser to test the page (page is 'live' [here](http://werkwel.andrew-millar.nl/WerkWel-moderator.html)). Thanks

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/BYOQskiuGU0 According to the Chrome forums if you have enabled it and it still says that, you may have malware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the DevTools settings? You might have accidentally enabled "Disable Javascript"

Comment: That's it, thanks. Somewhat irritating that the all the settings of chrome are so fragmented. Strange that this doesn't give any problems in other sites...

Comment: @Sl4rtib4rtf4st disable javascript only works if the devtools are open

Comment: Ah, that clears up an other issue I was having. The site did sometimes react as expected when I first opened it but then after checking for errors in the console it didn't, I didn't make the connection.